# How to handle "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: objective-c, macos, linker-errors, xcode5.1

I had an error like

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have searched, did all provided solution. but still same error. I have attached the screen shot of error page. Can anybody help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `ld: file not found: -lcurl`.  What do you think that means?

Comment: You are probably missing some sort of library that that is able to perform the command `-lcurl`

Comment: @trojanfoe there is no file in my project and headers also.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Plus you didn't answer my question.

Comment: @trojanfoe "CURL_LIBS='-lcurl " this is declared imported C file.

Comment: OK, so you need the curl library, if your program links with it.  I don't believe the curl library is a standard OSX library, so you need to supply that yourself.  I would recommend installing Macports and installing it from there (you will need to supply `-L/opt/local/lib` to the linker to find it).

Comment: @trojanfoe is supply this "-L/opt/local/lib" to Other Linker Path or Framework search path, can you tell me where is set this

Comment: I didn't get u. I already installed macports. and how to supply this. @trojanfoe sorry i'm new to mac development.

Comment: Other linker flags should be ok.  You need to have installed `curl` using Macports (check that `/opt/local/lib/libcurl*` exists).

Comment: @trojanfoe there is no curl install in mac, so i install curl using homebrew. is it right solution. the path is installed in  -L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib

Comment: I don't know about homebrew as I don't use it, but I know that curl does exist in macports.  Doing `sudo port install curl` should install both the command line `curl` utility and `libcurl`.

Comment: @trojanfoe I installed via port and set "/opt/local/lib/libcurl" to Other Liner Flags. is it correct setup?

Comment: @trojanfoe the error now shows "Can't map file, errno=22 file '/opt/local/lib/' for architecture x86_64"

Answer (score 0):

Does this link help?
http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/library-not-found-for-lcurl/12035

In summary:
Caused by adding AdMob or Flurry to the project.
Check Build Settings > Library Search Paths and ensure that they are correctly rooted so they point to the correct libraries. Others had some success in removing the $(SRCROOT) bit and turning them into absolute paths.